# Replacing sublists with their last element

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun rep(list)
(format t"~a~%" list)
    (cond
        ((null list) nil)
        ((atom (car list)) (cons (car list) (rep  (cdr list))))
        ((listp (car list))  (cons (car (reverse (car list))) (cdr list)))
        (t (rep list))
    )
)
```

Write a function to replace each sublist of a list with its last element.
     A sublist is an element from the first level, which is a list.
    Example:

```
(a (b c) (d (e (f)))) ==> (a c (e (f))) ==> (a c (f)) ==> (a c f)
     (a (b c) (d ((e) f))) ==> (a c ((e) f)) ==> (a c f)
```

I have the above problem to solve. Got it till one point but I'm stuck.
Apparently it doesn't go to the next elements in the list and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the code that you have _does_ do?

Comment: In your 3rd condition, `(car (reverse (car list)))` might itself be a list so it won't be fully processed. Also `(cdr list)` should be replaced by `(rep (cdr list))` or, likewise, it won't be fully processed. And optionally, a little simpler would be to replace `(car (reverse (car list)))` with `(car (last list))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it without using map functions

```
(defun rep(list)
    (cond
        ((null list) nil)
        ((listp (car list)) (rep (cons (car (reverse (car list))) (rep (cdr list)))))
        (t (cons (car list) (rep (cdr list))))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break it down like this:

```
(defun last-element (lst)
  (if (listp lst)
    (last-element (car (last lst)))
    lst))

(defun rep (lst)
  (when lst
    (cons (last-element (car lst)) (rep (cdr lst)))))
```

then

```
(rep '(a (b c) (d (e (f)))))
=> '(A C F)
```

Comment: Thanks,but I have to do it without map functions

Comment: Then just write your own map function; the breakdown still applies.